# Problem in getting the UID of the Invoking Firebase Cloud function in Flutter

Tags: firebase, function, cloud

I'm building a garbage management system app, so I'm using HTTPS firebase function to make this by creating a QR for the function that has been scanned by the user to invoke the function. So now I have a problem in grabbing the UI of the person who scans the QR code in the Flutter app.

```
exports.create = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
 return admin.firestore().collection('games').add({
   points: 0,
 })
});
```